# Add multiple Custom Columns in a Report

Tags: column, report-formula

I am trying to to count number of opportunities, that contain specific text in opportunity name.  I need fixed columns for example  CMC, CPC ,Training and so on.

Opportunity name looks like:    PQ CMC 356 + Training + TU

I can achieve this using a Row level formula Column using:
IF(CONTAINS(OPPORTUNITY_NAME, "CMC"),1,0)

This works correctly, but I am limited to one column only.  I need about 15

Comment: https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdoJvUAJ/increase-limit-of-row-level-formula-in-report . You'll need to rethink your approach by for example using formula and/or rollup fields at the object level and then reporting on that.